# How can I get the namespace where the Class is run?

Tags: php, namespaces

**I apologize in advance for my bad english.**
I hope you will understand by reading the codes.

How can I get the namespace where the Class is run?
But I don't want to pass **NAMEPSACE** as a parameter to the method.

#### Route.php

```
namespace sys;

class Route{
    static public function getNamespaceOfRunFile(){
        echo namespace;
    }
}
```

#### app/example.php

```
namespace app\example;
use sys\Route;

Route::getNamespaceOfRunFile(); //echo "app\example"
```

I have to get "app\example" inside the Route class.
Thanks..

Comment: this [code snippet](https://3v4l.org/I5UVL) might be short and sweet enough.

Comment: You can't go beyond `sys` maybe because my code use `$trace[0]['file']` and `[0]` is not the previous file you called (or caller). I did not test your new code but be careful that explode ``\\`` on file path maybe working only on Windows path or not. I recommend normalize them from any path separator to ``\\`` first.

Comment: I've updated code to get caller file in case you may still interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get namespace use `get_called_class()`, even `debug_backtrace()` can't find the namespace on **example.php** file.

The `get_called_class()` return `sys\Route` as used on `class::method()` called.

To find namespace of caller file like this need a little trick. First use back trace to get caller file and its content then use function created by [naholyr on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/naholyr/1885879) to extract only namespace.

Here is full source code for **Route.php**.

```php
namespace sys;

class Route{
    static public function getNamespaceOfRunFile(){
        $traces = debug_backtrace();
        // get caller file.
        foreach ($traces as $trace) {
            if (isset($trace['file']) && $trace['file'] !== __FILE__) {
                $file = $trace['file'];
                break;
            }
        }


        if (!empty($file) && is_file($file)) {
            $fileContents = file_get_contents($file);
            return (by_token($fileContents));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @link https://gist.github.com/naholyr/1885879 Original source code.
 */
function by_token ($src) {
    $tokens = token_get_all($src);
    $count = count($tokens);
    $i = 0;
    $namespace = '';
    $namespace_ok = false;
    while ($i < $count) {
        $token = $tokens[$i];
        if (is_array($token) && $token[0] === T_NAMESPACE) {
            // Found namespace declaration
            while (++$i < $count) {
                if ($tokens[$i] === ';') {
                    $namespace_ok = true;
                    $namespace = trim($namespace);
                    break;
                }
                $namespace .= is_array($tokens[$i]) ? $tokens[$i][1] : $tokens[$i];
            }
            break;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if (!$namespace_ok) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return $namespace;
    }
}
```